# High CPU runs in launchd

Tags: mac, launchd, cpu

[image][image: The print screen from the activity monitor]

My fan on my Mac has been running all the time. I did google some solution for this problem. However, I didn't see any error on the system.log
Could anybody have any better recommendation for my Mac.

Comment: If you switch to energy use - what apps are taking energy. Launchd is a worker and only is being asked to do work, the trick is to figure out who is asking for work. Your screen shot is too cropped to tell what’s happening. Please edit some details in the main post with the edit button.

Comment: @bmike I did add the energy use. In the meantime, my fan is still running and my keyboard has been really warm.

Comment: Wow. Very clean list. You can quit chrome just to rule that out and possibly reboot without using and web browsers until you’re sure the issue isn’t related to web browsing.

Comment: I experience the same high proc usage of launchd & UserEventAgent (maybe every three days up to two hours) and I usually resolve it by simply relaunching Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that launchd is trying to launch something that is failing  and it's just trying over and over and over again. I remember seeing something similar before.

First thing I'd recommend is downloading and running [EtreCheck](https://etrecheck.com). Amongst other things this will look at all your launch agents and launch daemons scripts and point out any that have missing components that might result in this repeated behaviour.

Look for items highlighted in red like in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of partial EtreCheck results]